# How to delete definite lines of a file which strats and ends with specific characters

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, text-extraction

I have a test file with many lines. I want to delete lines with a specific start and end characters.

here is my code:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as out: 
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if (line.startswith('E3T') and line.endswith('3')): 
           out.write(line)
        elif (line.startswith('E4Q') and line.endswith('3')): 
           out.write(line)
        elif (line.startswith('E4Q') and line.endswith('4')): 
           out.write(line)
        elif (line.startswith('E4Q') and line.endswith('3')): 
           out.write(line)
        elif line.startswith('BC'):
            break
```

this is my test.txt file

```
E3T 1 2 1 3 3
E3T 2 4 2 5 1
E3T 3 3 5 2 4
E3T 3326 2001 2008 1866 10
E4Q 3327 1869 2013 2011 1867 9
E4Q 3328 1867 2011 2012 1868 8
E4Q 3329 1870 2014 2013 1869 4
E3T 8542 4907 4908 4760 5
E3T 8543 4768 4909 4761 9
E3T 8544 4909 4763 4761 6
E3T 17203 9957 9964 10161 3
E3T 17204 9957 10161 9959 2
BC  1 "Zulauf: Temperatur" 12 0 1 "HYDRO_WT-2D"
BC_DEF 12 1 "Temperatur [°C]" 5 "Zeit [s]" "Temperatur [°C]"
```

And the output should be like this:

```
E3T 1 2 1 3 3
E3T 3 3 5 2 4
E4Q 3329 1870 2014 2013 1869 4
E3T 17203 9957 9964 10161 3
```

I think, it does not work because of the spaces. Is there any pythonic way of doing this or I have to split the lines and then compare the first and last characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read a line in that way there is either a new-line or a new-line/line-feed character at the end of it that is usually 'invisible' to you. You need to deal with that somehow, otherwise `endswith` will process it rather than the character you want to process. Then, when you output a line you need to put the new-line character back.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as out: 

    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        line = line.strip()
        if (line.startswith('E3T') and line.endswith('3')): 
           out.write(line+'\n')
        elif (line.startswith('E4Q') and line.endswith('3')): 
           out.write(line+'\n')
        elif (line.startswith('E4Q') and line.endswith('4')): 
           out.write(line+'\n')
        elif (line.startswith('E4Q') and line.endswith('3')): 
           out.write(line+'\n')
        elif line.startswith('BC'):
            break
```

In this case I've used `strip` to discard white space at the beginning and end of each line. This is a very crude approach. It would be better to use,

```
line = line.rstrip()
```

which strips white space from only the right end of a string.

EDIT, in answer to the question in a comment:

Replace the last line above with these lines,

```
    out.write(line+'\n')
else:
    continue
```

Comment: thank you for the solution! What should I do if I want to write the rest of the lines and don't break! which means the rest of the file should be as same as the input file!